# Windows 7 batch - get last octet of IPv4 address and set environment variable

Tags: batch-file, ipv4, setx

I have Windows 7 machines that get imaged, and after imaging I have to set the environment variable STATION to the last octet of the machine's IP address. How would I parse the IP address and grab the last octet to set the STATION variable?

This only sets the variable to the full ip address:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%j in ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| findstr Reply') do (set localip=%%j)
SETX /m STATION "%localip:~11%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it with another `for`:

```
for /f "Tokens=4 delims=." %%a in (%localip%) do set lastOctett=%%a
```

May I suggest:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1') do for /f "tokens=4 delims=." %%b in ("%%a") do SETX /m STATION %%b
```

(I used a different method to get the IP, because yours depends on local settings - for example on my computer  I would have to search for `Antwort` instead of `Reply`. But the syntax is the same in all languages, so the IP is always enclosed by `[` and `]`)

Comment: Thank you so much! It's people like you that have helped me branch out into so many different fields of IT. Keep up the good fight!